# How to include only a single folder in Bamboo build plan

Tags: glob, bamboo

I need Bamboo to build the project automatically when a file in "api" subfolder changes. When a file in any other subfolder changes the bamboo build plan shouldn't run.

Folder structure:

```
project
  - api
  - ui
  - core
```

In the Plan Configuration repositories tab, from the **"Include / exclude files"** dropdown I have selected the following option

```
Include only changes that matches the following pattern
```

and I have tried the following patterns:

```
.*/api/.*
api/
api/*
api\/*
api/**
/api/*
```

but the build plan isn't running. With "Include / exclude files" dropdown set to None the build plan runs (but does so when a file changes in any other subfolder also)

I can't split the project up to different repositories.

What pattern should I use or is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern that ended up working was

```
api/.*
```

Comment: For clarification, `api` is at the _root_ of your repo, right?  Not `project/api`?  Thus you'd clone something like https://github.com/user/project.git ?

Answer (score 2):

It's a regular expression from the root of the checkout supposedly, although I have not used this feature.  Here are some of their examples:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO052/_planRepositoryIncludeExcludeFilesExamples?_ga=2.91083610.1778956526.1502832020-118211336.1443803386

What you might try is let it checkout the whole thing without the include filter set, and don't let it delete the working directory.  Look on the filesystem and verify the path from the root of the working directory.  Then test your regex against the whole path relative from that working directory.